# commons pool jar 2.2 : is there any replacement of GenericObjectPool.Config class?

Tags: java, release, nested-class, apache-commons-pool

I just studying redis. In my text-book, they use GenericObjectPool.Config class which supported in apache commons pool jar version 1.6.
 However, for now that class has disappeared. So I want to know is there any replacement of 'GenericObjectPool.Config'. 
 in additionally, where can I find replacement of the field 'WHEN_EXHAUSTED_BLOCK'?

Thanks a lot in advanced:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I am answering my own.
in conclusion, jedis does not support latest version of apache commons pool.
for instance, JedisPool class gets GenericObjectPool.Config instance as a parameter of constructor which is not supported anymore in version 2.1.0.

Anyway, I stil some questions about replacements of some disappears.